# What would convince rational people that a given book has been written by the Devil?

Tags: internal-consistency, gods, demons

A central part of my story involves a certain book that was allegedly written by the Devil himself. However, my protagonists are rational and skeptic people, they do not believe such outrageous claims (*extraordinary claims must be supported by extraordinary evidence*).

Is there a away to convince them, unambiguously, that the contents of the book are indeed truly and verily the words of the Devil?

**Note**: if it helps, feel free to replace "Devil" by any malevolent super-creature that is very unlikely to exist (Cthulhu, ...).

Comment: How is this about building a fictional world? It seems like this question is more about the actions of your characters.

Comment: Are you asking how can rational and skeptic people believe that something has been written by an entity which they are sure does not exist?

Comment: Actually working magic? Book talking to them? Basically any paranormal reproduceable effect?

Comment: Is this just a normal regular book, what are its contents? does the devil still interact with people? More information is needed

Comment: This is not answerable without knowledge about working of mystical powers in  your world. For example, is devil appearing out if thin  air, saying "I made this!" and disappearing again  possible?

Comment: What powers does the devil or supernatural entities have? can they predict the future? Do they know the unknowable? Do they have secret forbidden knowledge? What does the devil have in this case that Bob the leader of a standard cult does not have?

Comment: For me, it would convince me if this "Devil" or "Cthulhu" told me they have written this book. (I might still believe they are lying but at least I'd believe they had motivation and means to do it.)

Comment: I agree that this is not a worldbuilding question, but it is a fun question, so a comment: You suggest it takes effort to convince "rational and skeptical" people, that extraordinary proof is required for extraordinary claims.  A MASSIVE amount of the world's population believes in some holy work, whether is be Muhammad, Christ, Jehova, Buddah, and the various Hidu works.  You seem to think 95% of our world is irrational.  All it really takes is a philosophy that can be segued into social mores.  So the real question is, what't the nature of your text?  Are we killing babies?

Comment: @JBH Hahaha that might be an option. What do you have in mind?

Comment: That's not for me to answer.  We need data, and that might allow you to either reopen this question or (more likely) to post a new question.  We need to understnad the rules of your world and we're willing to help you develop those rules.  The more narrow the question, the more likely an answer. Is the population of your world very Earth-like? or is it filled with Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster skeptics?  What is the history of the devil's book?  What are its goals?  What are the practices it demands?  How invasive is the devil in people's daily lives? etc.

Comment: But remember, as you ask this question, to be asked here it must be about your world, not your story.  We deal with framework, not plot development.  To that end, we're more interested in the backstory than the forestory.  Finally, asking "how to convince everybody" is too broad, because how do we predict 9 billion opinions?  Asking "Given this description, what subtle twist to the book can I introduce that makes it more consumable?" is closer to our kind of question.

Comment: I could see a question working along the lines of "What would convince rational people that an object is supernatural in origin" *without* specific characterization of either the people or the author. As it stands, though, it's currently too plot-specific to be a *world*building question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the animé *Death Note*, notebooks exist that have supernatural composition and powers. Generally speaking, if a person's name is written in a notebook, that person dies.

These notebooks are usually owned and used by death gods, with pens or pencils that come from their death world. In one episode, forensics specialists from Japan's police remark that they have analyzed the ink from some of the writings in such a notebook, and they could not determine what the ink was - presumably because it was literally something from another world.

You could use the death notes as a source of inspiration. Your devil book **will not convince skeptics unless it is able to do something "supernatural"**. Among us, there is a saying:

> Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence

<sub>**Minor edit:** I had not seen that you had the very same sentence in the question itself.</sub>

Some ways in which the book could display interesting phenomena. You could use one, or a combination of as many as you want:

- It cannot be destroyed by any simple methods (such as tearing or fire);
- It rewrites itself in one way or another;
- Everybody who comes in contact with it dies, no exception;
- It describes future events with enough precision to negate accusations of being right by being vague, i.e.: rather than make prophecies along the lines of "a star will fall from the sky and strike upon the glass city", it should say something like "asteroid [astronomical number of an asteroid yet to be discovered and numbered] will impact upon [name of country] on the 3rd of August of the year [year number] of the Lord, harvesting [approximate amount of dead people] souls".
- It teaches spells or incantations that actually work.

Etc., etc.

It will be more convincing as well if spectography cannot determine the composition of the paper and ink.

Comment: More ideas: - The leather bound book is analyzed and turns out to be human. DNA tests show it comes from the person who has touched it the most. - Each time its read there are new pages listing the readers sins.  - At first the ink is faded and old, as its handled it becomes a bright red, almost moist to the touch, the person using it begins to suffer anemia. - Whenever it is damaged, it repairs itself while unseen, the person who damaged it suffers similar injuries. - The owner writes a new page in his sleep. GPS coordinates and death toll of a disaster that happens within a week or less.

Comment: None of these would convince me that the book was written by a supernatural evil, only that it was made by something technologically superior.

Comment: @RealSubtle Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic, and any sufficiently over-analyzed magic becomes indistinguishable from technology. Some people would face Diablo himself and think he is actually an alien with access to singularity-level technology. Some people would face the Protoss and believe them to be angels. You can't convince absolutely everybody when it comes to this kind of thing.

Comment: @RealSubtle I agree and that's because I think the most important part about Death Note has been left out: One of those demons came with the book and appeared in "person". That was the actual proof

Comment: @Raditz_35 I'll be the devil's advocate (pun unintended) here and claim that a) there is no proof that Ryuuk is not actually a Zeta with advanced technology or a construct of the Matrix and b) he was not the creator of the death notes - we don't see Light or any other human talking directly to the Shinigami King.

Comment: @Renan Enough to convince though if not mathematical proof. I only know half the words you are using btw

Comment: @Raditz_35 `I only know half the words you are using btw` maybe we have seen the story from different sources. I have not watched the Netflix movie, but I have watched the animation and read the comics. In those, Ryuuk and other death gods answer to a king (the Shinigami ("Death God") King), who is the actual provider of death notes. It is from him that the death gods acquire new death notes when their ones get full.

Comment: *It cannot be destroyed by any simple methods (such as tearing or fire);* — wasn't new Canadian banknotes supposed to be tear and fire resistant? I think this property is well within our tech level.

Comment: @Mołot resistant, yes, but immune? I think not.

Comment: @Molot Yes, but Canadian money is made out of plastic.

Comment: @RealSubtle what's more likely, an entity with technology indistinguishable from supernatural powers appears and is a liar who is trying to specifically trick you, or, an entity with supernatural powers appears?

Comment: @Shane I don't think there is enough empirical data on that.

Comment: @Shane It would entirely depend on the circumstances. Also, beings classed as "evil" are supposed to be untrustworthy by default.

Answer (score 1):

St. Augustine talks about evil as a total lack of virtue. In Christianity, there is no 'dark energy', the Devil cannot create *anything*, he can only exploit a person's free will to turn them away from God & Virtue. I'd suggest reading CS Lewis' Screwtape letters.

How does the book convince your characters that it is legit? That's up to you. Probably a spell that works. Keep in mind, though, that spells only work because God or a demon makes it work. No human has inherent magical powers in Christian theology.

Comment: I think the OP didn't mean to include Christian specific Devil, as it is possible to use any other evil entity. Though I think it is a rather interesting idea of a creepy book that drives people absolutely crazy and diabolic - as far from God as possible.

Comment: @user2851843 I believe the Necronomicon has that effect in the works of H.P. Lovecraft.

Comment: Answering with, "Make it up," does not satisfy as an answer to any question.

Comment: To use/paraphrase an expression: **one man's virtue is another man's vice**. To the religious, faith — i.e. to believe through lack of, or in spite of, evidence — is a great virtue. To the skeptic, faith is abominable. The debate on what is a virtue and what is a vice is just the ages old discourse on ethics.

Comment: How can a demon make a spell work if the only thing the devil can do is trick people into turning away from God? In Christian mythology, are demons MORE powerful than the devil?